# write_graphviz does not work when vertex has property

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am learning boost::graph and trying to add name property to Vertex. However, after doing that, write_graphviz does not save anything (without this property, it works).

Header file:

```
struct VertexProps
{
    std::string name;
};

struct EdgeProps
{
    double weight;
};

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProps, EdgeProps>;
using Vertex = boost::adjacency_list<>::vertex_descriptor;
using Edge = std::pair<boost::adjacency_list<>::edge_descriptor, bool>;
using EdgeList = std::pair<boost::adjacency_list<>::edge_iterator,
    boost::adjacency_list<>::edge_iterator>;
```

Cpp file:

```
Vertex vertex = boost::add_vertex({std::move(vertexName)}, g);

std::filebuf fb;
fb.open("output.txt", std::ios::out);
std::ostream os(&fb);
write_graphviz(os, g, boost::make_label_writer(get(&VertexProps::name, g)), boost::make_label_writer(get(&EdgeProps::weight, g)));
fb.close();
```

The file should contain graph, however I can see only:

```
digraph G {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear what you differently but here's a self-contained example based on the above:

**<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EImjDtuRY0I74n3s)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>

struct VertexProps { std::string name; };
struct EdgeProps { double weight; };

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, VertexProps, EdgeProps>;

int main(){
    Graph g;

    auto vertex = add_vertex({"MyVertexName"}, g);

    write_graphviz(std::cout, g,
        make_label_writer(get(&VertexProps::name, g)),
        make_label_writer(get(&EdgeProps::weight, g)));
}
```

Which prints

```
digraph G {
0[label=MyVertexName];
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I don't know why it didn't worked previously